# ANGULAR 4 : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in console

Tags: angular, subscribe

I get ERROR

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

```
  this.subscription=this.MyService.List().
   subscribe(data => 
  {
    this.arrayTmp = data;
  });
```

Service file :

```
 List(){
      return this.http.get(MY JSON URL)
      .pipe(map(res => {
        return res;         
      }));
  }
```

Comment: Can you share stackblitz of your code. Though your code looks perfect.

Comment: More context is needed, please post the whole class here.

Comment: Not that it would solve anything, but you don't need that pipe since you're not doing anything with the result in `List()`. `return this.http.get(...)` is enough